# Automate restoration of visual effects after a WebEx call ends

Tags: windows, windows-registry, visual-effects, webex

When I participate in a WebEx call that involves screen sharing (even if I'm not sharing my screen), WebEx disables some of the visual effects (Windows 10 1709) under "Advanced System Settings">Advanced>Performance>Settings, notably "Show window contents while dragging".

When the call ends, the effects remain disabled. To get them back I have to open up the dialog (which still shows everything as checked and set to "Adjust for best appearance"), switch it off of best appearance, and then switch it back and hit OK.

I used ProcMon to sniff the reg keys that get set when I hit OK on the dialog box, but setting them manually doesn't restore the effects.

How can I either prevent WebEx from disabling the effects or script restoring them to a single button push?

Answer (score 0):

These settings are found in the registry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`.

For example, "Show window contents while dragging" is found in the key
`DragFullWindows`, and its value should be `1` to enable.
To apply, you will need to sign out and sign in again or to restart the computer.

Documentation about `DragFullWindows` and other options can be found
in this [Microsoft article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978603.aspx).

Comment: I'm specifically looking for a solution that doesn't require logging out or rebooting; I want to do the same thing that the dialog I mentioned in my question does.

Comment: You can try, as after all this works for webex without any of this. At most, a little script that kills Explorer and restarts it is the same as logout+in.

Comment: It's already 1 after WebEx does its damage.

Comment: If you kill explorer and restart it, is this restored? You can do that via a .bat script with two lines: `taskkill /f /im explorer.exe` and `start explorer.exe `.

Comment: It is not restored.

Comment: Sorry, I admit to being stumped by the problem.

Comment: if you're savvy with programming this answer has info on how to change this setting programmatically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29551557/504398